# ¿Cómo desconectar a mi usuario de la cola de mensajes en AS400?

Tags: as400

He realizado un query en el entorno `AS400` mediante `STRSQL` y al parecer se quedo colgado por lo que decidí cerrar la ventana después de esperar un tiempo. Sin embargo ahora que ingreso me aparece el siguiente mensaje:

[image: error_as400]

Entiendo que esto hace que cualquier cosa que haga desde ahora en este nuevo login, no se podrá asignar algo al spool de mi usuario.

Además, al tener el usuario retenido he tenido que cambiar el nombre de mi estación porque no me dejaba ni loguear.

Comment: No sé cómo resolver el problema que tienes, pero si te conectas a una bd en AS400 (supongo de un DB2 u otra de IBM) puedes utilizar utilitarios que tienen cliente en Windows y así evitar estas situaciones.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero donde trabajo la mayoría usa este entorno, y cuando necesito encontrar una opción entre el cliente de windows y este entorno se complica :(.

Comment: Lo decia para la ejecución de consultas (queries) y otras operaciones contra la bd. Es cierto que hay varias cosas que solo puedes hacer a través de la consola. Espero realmente que alguien pueda apoyarte con esto.

Answer (score 1):

Si eres usuario administrador puedes usar `WRKACTJOB` y finalizar la tarea ejecutada por tu usuario y dispositivo anterior, usa de preferencia la opción <kbd>4</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> deberas dar <kbd>Enter</kbd> y así finalizar el proceso que se está ejecutando.

Para desactivar la estación que estabas usando en ese momento usa `WRKCGFSTS *DEV`, este te mostrará los dispositivos , deberás buscar el que estabas usando (nombre) y usar la opción <kbd>2</kbd> "Desactivar".

Así ya podrás loguearte con tu dispositivo anterior.